# Frequency Histogram in C

Tags: c

can someone give me a hint on how a histogram's pseudo code would look like?

Comment: This question needs much more detail.

Comment: Why, because the question is short? How many ways of doing a standard histogram are there?

Comment: Because he doesn't say what he wants or where he is stuck. Naming the kind of data he wants to stick in it would be good too. I had to guess as did others.

Comment: Continued by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413725/console-doesnt-display-histogram and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415348/design-a-frequncy-histogram-without-pointers-in-c.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How to structure and fill a histogram?

Trivial case is just a count per bin:

```
/* needs error checking, badly */
int *buildHist(int bins, double min, double max, int n, double *data){
   double *hist=malloc(bins*sizeof(int));
   if (hist == NULL) return hist;
   for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
      int bin=int( (data[i]-min)/((max-min)/(bins)) );
      if ( (bin>=0) && (bin<n) ) hist[bin]++;
   }
   return hist;
}
```

For a weighted histogram, the array must be of floating point type.

With more data (over- and under-flow counts, accumulated statistics...or even to keep the limits in the same place as the count), use a structure that includes the array.

Incremental filling is often desired, but should be obvious from here.

Output depends a great deal on what display technology you have at hand.

Comment: a friend of mine helped me get started, but I don't know what he intended to do... here's what I have 

void computeHistogram(int data[], int data_size, int histo[], int histo_size) {

 int min = 99999999;
 int max = -99999999;
 int i = 0;
 while(i<data_size){
  if(data[i] < min){
   min = data[i];
}
  if(data[i]>max){
   max = data[i];
  }
 }
 printf("min of data is %d", min);

}

Comment: It looks like he intends to set the limits dynamically. Make one pass through the data to find the limiting values, then make *another* pass through the data to fill the histogram. Your firend gave you the limit finding pass, and the filling pass will look like the one I exhibit above.

Comment: thank you dmckee, but I was instructed not to use pointers.... is there an alternative? thanks!

Comment: Substitute arrays like your friend did, and allocate both arrays on the stack in the calling routine. And ditch the `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'd probably have a bunch of printf statements at the top for your headers to give some meaning to the data. Then maybe a line of dashes or equals or something to work as a separator.

Then below that, loop through an array with the values you wish to plot. One on each line.