# Order of control flow execution within a while loop

Tags: c

I have written the following code when solving one of the early chapter exercises of the [C programming language](https://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628) book from K&R. The program uses the built-in C function `getchar()` to read through the user input and prints a horizontal histogram picturing the length of each word. The code is below

Related discussion:
[Print a Histogram based on word lengths (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989790/print-a-histogram-based-on-word-lengths-c)

```
//  Print a histogram of lengths of words in input

// 1. Capture a word in input (differentiate state inside a word vs outside)
// 2. Capture its length 
// 3. Store its length in an array (array size = number of words)

#define MAXWORDS 10 // Maximum number of words is 10
#define IN 1 // State when inside a word
#define OUT 0 // State when outisde a word

int main() {

    int c, i, length, nword, state; 
    /*
    c <- captures teveryheverye character in input stream
    i <- sets the data in the array
    j <- represents the length of a word
    nword <- total number of words 
    */
    int maxlengths[MAXWORDS]; // array of size MAXWORDS

    // Initialisation
    state = OUT;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXWORDS; i++)
        maxlengths[i] = 0; 

    length = 0;
    nword = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        // CONDITION 1
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            state = OUT;
        }
        // CONDITION 2
        else if (nword == 0) {
            state = IN;
            ++j;
        }
        // CONDITION 3
        else if (state == IN) {
            ++j; 
        }
        // CONDITION 4
        else if (state == OUT) {
            maxlengths[nword] = j;
            ++ nword;
            j = 0;
            state = IN;
        }

    }

    for (i = 0; i < MAXWORDS; i++) {
        printf("length of word %d: ", i+1);
        for (j = 0; j < maxlengths[i]; j ++)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand how the control flow conditions get evaluated for a simple input character stream say: "A\nA\nEOF". We have 4 characters here, 2 "A"s each followed by a new line character and ending with control+D as EOF signal.

In my understanding, there is a delay between the program reading a character as input and executing the corresponding condition where the length of the input gets stored in the array `maxlengths`. When the user types the first "A", this triggers the second condition to be evaluated. Upon reading the second character which is "\n", the code triggers the first condition where state is set to OUT. Upon reading the third character which is the second "A" the code enters the third loop where condition 4 gets executed and the length of the first word "A" is recorded in the array. Susbequently, when reading the last newline character in the sequence, condition 3 gets executed as state would have been set to IN in the previous iteration and the length of the second word gets incremented. My understanding is based on the fact that the control flow evaluates each condition in order and whenever it encounters a condition that is true, it executes the body and skips all the remaining condition. In my logic, I do not see at which iteration does the length of the second word get stored in the array.

Comment: `getchar()` does not return until you press "enter".

Comment: `else (state == OUT) {` Typo?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. https://godbolt.org/z/v4Ec3ecdc

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

As written, conditions 3 and 4 can never execute.  `nword` is initially 0 and as long as it is 0, condition 2 will be true, and as neither condition 1 nor condition 2 ever set it to anything else, condition 2 will ALWAYS be true.

This is the way `if`..`else if` chains work -- each condition is evaluated in turn until one is true and that alternative will run and all the rest of the `else` clauses will be skipped.  There's nothing special about the while.

Comment: I have edited the code to correct the type with the missing if. I understand conditions 3 and 4 will never execute because 2 is always true and as you clearly mention it, the body of 2 will execute. How can I explain then that the code produces the right results ?